# Como usar Geolocation API com QtWebkit?

Tags: c++, qt, geolocalização, qtwebkit

É possível usar [*Geolocation API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Using_geolocation) com *aplicações Desktop* usando `QWebView`?

> - Tentei [Qt WebKit and HTML5 geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865290/1518921), mas não funciona.
> - Tentei [it's the qt5 position api support for desktop app(like mac or windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27359547/1518921), mas está resposta é sobre as APIs do Qt, eu quero saber se não é possível nos Desktops então é talvez seja possível customizar o "evento", assim como é feito com `qwebkitplatformplugin` que é usado para customizar algumas características no `qtwebkit` (MultipleSelections, Notifications, Haptics, TouchInteraction, FullScreenVideoPlayer e SpellChecker).

Tentei usar `PermissionGrantedByUser`, mas não funciona:

```
void WebPage::permissionRequested(QWebFrame* frame, Feature feature)
{
    switch (feature) {
        case Geolocation:
            qDebug() << "GEO-Location: PermissionGrantedByUser";
            setFeaturePermission(frame, feature, PermissionGrantedByUser);
        break;
        default:
            qDebug() << "";
    }
}
```

- Tentei `QT += positioning`, mas não funciona
- Tentei `TARGET.CAPABILITY += NetworkServices Location`, mas não funciona. acredito que esta *flag* seja para smartphones, como Symbian.

Os eventos `displayLocation` e `watchPosition` nunca são disparados e se usar `{ timeout: ... }` irá mostrar `Timeout expired` após o tempo determinado:

```
<script>
function displayError(err) {
    document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = ("Código de erro: " + err.code +
        " / mensagem: " + err.message);
}

function displayLocation(position) {
    document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = [
        "latitude:" + position.coords.latitude,
        "longitude:" + position.coords.longitude
    ].join(", ");
}

function getMyLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(a, b, c) {
            console.log(a, b, c);
            document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = "Testando...";
        });
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError, {
            enableHighAccuracy: false,
            timeout: 1000,
            maximumAge: 0
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = "Geo-Localização não suportado";
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    getMyLocation();
};
</script>
<div id="geo"></div>
```

Acredito que eu tenha que criar um plugin com *Qt* e colocar na pasta `qtDir/compiler/plugins/position`, mas eu não sei por onde começar a criar este plugin.

Como posso fazer isto?

É possível customizar os eventos e enviar coordenadas simuladas ou por uma biblioteca de terceiros (eu não estou pedindo por um biblioteca e nem por alternativas em JavaScript) para o `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`?

---

### Informações extras

Se usar `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` no modo de depuração (`debug mode`) o *Application Output* retorna isto (note que a primeira linha do *log* é gerada pelo `WebPage::permissionRequested`):

```
GEO-Location: PermissionGrantedByUser
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpoll.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpoll.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.position.sourcefactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "positionpoll"
        ],
        "Monitor": true,
        "Position": false,
        "Priority": 1000,
        "Provider": "positionpoll",
        "Satellite": false
    },
    "className": "QGeoPositionInfoSourceFactoryPoll",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328704
}


"The plugin 'C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpoll.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)"
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpolld.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpolld.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.position.sourcefactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "positionpoll"
        ],
        "Monitor": true,
        "Position": false,
        "Priority": 1000,
        "Provider": "positionpoll",
        "Satellite": false
    },
    "className": "QGeoPositionInfoSourceFactoryPoll",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 328704
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("positionpoll")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/projects/webview-example/debug/position" ...
```

Em outras palavras, quando executo o JavaScript `navigator.geolocation` o *Qt* chama o `C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/position/qtposition_positionpoll.dll`, mas não retorna nenhuma informação de volta para o `QWebView`.